# Creating IPA file for iPad testing

Tags: iphone

I need to give an IPA file for testing in my clients i Pad. I have given him 3 IPA files so far and all of them crashed when installing. The client says when clicking on the app icon a black screen appears and closes immediately taking him back to the home screen.
How do i create an IPA file. 
I need clear steps from creating Provisioning profile, creating apple id,setting the Bundle identifier etc.I have gone thr' many forums and links but all of them seem to confuse me. I use xcode 4.2.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this video tutorial : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAdV16nRLp8, i haven't seen it though, looking at comments it seems helpful.

Comment: And have you tested the app on your device? Because the usual problem for not able to create a valid IPA is app not being able to install it on device. Your problem seems like a crash rather than invalid IPA. Try your app on the device first.

Comment: I have no real device here. Thats the main pblm.It runs fine in simulator

Comment: I strongly suggest you get a device, because there are many problems that won't be replicated on simulator.

Comment: @iNoob: Yes I have asked for one. I got the crash log from clients device but it seems to be too complicated.

Comment: You'll learn to understand it with time and reading up on what do crash logs mean. You can understand it better when you put exception breakpoint in your app and running on device. So it really is very important to test on device.

Comment: From the description it looks like there is no problem with the ipa as it installs fine. But the app is crashing on startup. So you'd better start investigating the crash.

Comment: @lostInTransit: The crash log seem to be too confusing.

Comment: You can probably post that here and someone can help you out. There definitely seems to be a problem with the code, not the ipa. Try symbolicating the crash as well and see if that helps. If you are not testing on an actual device, do that, use debugging and you'll find the problem easily.

Comment: symbolicating the crash?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me a few times when I created an ipa file using an online service and was unable to install it according to their directions. It turned out that my phone was too full. When I deleted some applications that I never used anyway, I was able to install as directed.